# Retrieve window's username from a Asp.net core web app

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, ubuntu, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core 3 web app hosted on an Ubuntu server using Apache.
The app has a login, where the user provides a username and password, and we authenticate against an Identity Server.
In the login flow (in the Identity Server), we check if the user exists in Active Directory (by using the Novell.Directory.Ldap nuget package), if it does, then we retrieve the user data and create the corresponding token, otherwise, we go to our database and check if the user exists there.

This login flow works properly, but there is a new requirement that says that we need to implement a Single Sign-On. So if the user is logged with an account that is asscoiated to the Active Directory domain, then, the user is allowed to access our web app without providing username / password.

At first, I thought that maybe we could automatically retrieve the username in the client app and provide that username to the identity server without a password to finally query Active Directory to check if the user exists. The problem is that I'm not sure how am I supposed to retrieve that username....

Is there any way i can retrieve the Window's username from the client app?

Thanks

Comment: `user is logged with an account that is asscoiated to the Active Directory domain, then, the user is allowed to access our web app without providing username / password` - so what does he use to log in? (supposed that at the end you said `without providing username`)

Comment: @KingKing For example: There is a user called "Testing" in Active direcotry. If this user, access his windows machine with that account, and opens up our web app, we should automatically sign in the user because his account is in Active directory.

Comment: is your web server/host part of the same AD? Looks like your question is a bit misleading by the title. It seems to involve Windows authentication

Comment: @KingKing yep, it is part of the same domain.

Comment: If you are requested to implement a Single Sign On, you should probably be looking in either SAML SSO (with a second party identity provider) or use Kerberos to log in.